# tengo problema al querer instalar beautifulsoup4 y requests

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Me muestra este error la verdad es que no tengo mucho programando en python si me pudieran ayudar a solucionar este error o saber que versiones me pueden servir o como validarlo se los agradeceria

> Collecting requests==2.18.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
>   Using cached requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl Collecting
>   beautifulsoup4-4.6.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))   Could not
>   find a version that satisfies the requirement beautifulsoup4-4.6.0
>   (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: ) No matching
>   distribution found for beautifulsoup4-4.6.0 (from -r requirements.txt
>   (line 2))

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Fito,  ¿podrias añadir más información?: Sistema operativo, versión de Python (3.6, 2.7, 3.5, etc) sobre la que quieres instalar, si tienes más versiones de Python instaladas en el sistema, si usas Anaconda o entornos virtuales y  cómo intentas instalar (qué comando usas para ello).

Comment: si tengo Python 2.7.10 y Python 3.6.2 no tengo anaconda el comando es pip install -r requirements.txt  y quiero instalar requests==2.18.4 beautifulsoup4-4.6.0

Comment: ¿Sistema operativo? ¿Sobre que versión de Python vas a instalar, sobre la 2.7 o sobre  la 3.6? ¿Cual es el contenido de requieremenrs.txt?

Comment: Fito parece que usas macOs, no tengo demasiada experiencia con este sistema y su actual gestión de permisos pero el problema actual es claro: no tienes permisos suficientes. Una opción sería instalar solo en el usuario actual con `pip install --user -r requirements.txt` o usar entornos virtuales. No recomiendo instalar con permisos de superusuario por norma general ( `sudo pip.... `)

Comment: Si, así como dice @FJSevilla en ese caso lo recomendable es usar `sudo pip` aunque con pip estas usando el python que viene por defecto en el sistema y no se recomienda usar ese, intenta instalar un python nuevo para que puedas descargar sin permisos de superusuario, o crea un entorno virtual